# Getting this error: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Tags: c, formatting

```
  printf("\nEnter Matrix A\n", i + 1, j + 1);
  for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
      scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }

  printf("\nEnter Matrix B\n", i + 1, j + 1);
  for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
      scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
    }
```

When I compile this, I get an error message saying main.c:9:10: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args] on lines 10 and 16. I’m new to programming C so any tips would be helpful.

Comment: Look at the `printf` format string on those two lines, then look at the arguments you're passing.

Comment: `printf("\nEnter Matrix A\n", i + 1, j + 1);` — how many `%` specifiers are there?

Comment: Why do you have  `i + 1, j + 1` in the `printf()` arguments? Those variables don't get set until you go into the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem in the code:** You are giving extra arguments in the **printf()** function without specifying **format specifier**. The syntax of **printf()** is `int printf ( const char * format, ... );`

You can check [official](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) or [this](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/cstdio/printf) websites to understand details of how to use **printf()** function.

**Solution to your problem**:
At line 10 and 16 you can use `%d` format specifier for two arguments. The code will be `printf("\nEnter Matrix A: %d, %d\n", i + 1, j + 1);`

However, you should not use those lines to imply matrix dimensions. You can write  something like `printf("\nEnter Matrix A: which is (%d by %d) matrix\n", r, c);` to denote matrix dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see you are just missing the %i for your printf. No big deal. That what it was telling you. If this helps please give green check. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int r, c, a[100][100], b[100][100], sum[100][100], i, j;
  printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
  scanf("%d", &r);
  printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
  scanf("%d", &c);

  printf("\nEnter Matrix A\n %i,%i", i + 1, j + 1);
  for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
      scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }

  printf("\nEnter Matrix B\n %i,%i", i + 1, j + 1);
  for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
      scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
    }


  for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
      sum[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
    }

  printf("\nA + B = \n");
  for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
      printf("%d   ", sum[i][j]);
      if (j == c - 1) {
        printf("\n\n");
      }
    }

  return 0;
}
```